# Не работают фильтры

Tags: php, фильтры

купил движок, и у меня почемуто не работает фильтр **(payout_method)**. Но остальные работают, могли бы подсказать из-за чего так происходит, и как это можно решить, в бд все добавил.

```
<div class="row table-filter-container">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <?php echo form_open($form_action, ['method' => 'GET']); ?>

    <div class="item-table-filter" style="width: 80px; min-width: 80px;">
        <label><?php echo trans("show"); ?></label>
        <select name="show" class="form-control">
            <option value="15" <?php echo ($this->input->get('show', true) == '15') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>15</option>
            <option value="30" <?php echo ($this->input->get('show', true) == '30') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>30</option>
            <option value="60" <?php echo ($this->input->get('show', true) == '60') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>60</option>
            <option value="100" <?php echo ($this->input->get('show', true) == '100') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>100</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="item-table-filter" style="width: 150px; min-width: 150px;">
        <label><?php echo trans("withdraw_method"); ?></label>
        <select name="payout_method" class="form-control">
            <option value="paypal" <?php echo ($this->input->get('payout_method', true) == 'paypal') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>PayPal</option>
            <option value="iban" <?php echo ($this->input->get('payout_method', true) == 'iban') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>IBAN</option>
            <option value="swift" <?php echo ($this->input->get('payout_method', true) == 'swift') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Swift</option>
            <option value="CreditCard" <?php echo ($this->input->get('payout_method', true) == 'CreditCard') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Credit Card</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="item-table-filter">
        <label><?php echo trans("search"); ?></label>
        <input name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo trans("user_id"); ?>" type="search" value="<?php echo html_escape($this->input->get('q', true)); ?>" <?php echo ($rtl == true) ? 'dir="rtl"' : ''; ?>>
    </div>

    <div class="item-table-filter md-top-10" style="width: 65px; min-width: 65px;">
        <label style="display: block">&nbsp;</label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn bg-purple"><?php echo trans("filter"); ?></button>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: *купил движок* - вы купили без поддержки?

Comment: Попробуйте подробнее описать проблему на каком фреймворке написан.

Comment: Написан на Codeigniter